# Find all entire functions $f$ satisfying $\Re(f(z))\leq\frac{2}{|z|}$ whenever $|z|>1\iff \frac{1}{|z|}< 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been working in the following:

> Find all the entire function $f$ satisfying $$\Re (f(z))\leq \frac{2}{|z|}\quad\textrm{  whenever } \quad|z|>1\iff \frac{1}{|z|}< 1$$

*Solution:* Suppose that $f$ is entire with under these conditions. First, $\Re f\leq 2$. Second, consider $g(z)=\exp(f(z))$, then $g$ is entire too and 
$$
|g(z)|=|\exp(f(z))|=\exp(\Re(f(z)))\leq e^2.
$$ 
Hence, by  Liouville’s theorem, $g(z)=C$. 
Finally, we observe $$g(z)=\exp(f(z))\Longrightarrow g'(z)=f'(z)\exp(f(z))\Longrightarrow 0=f'(z)$$
meaning that $f(z)$ must be a constant.

I just wonder if I miss steps or I'm wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A few corrections . . .

- Minor correction: 
  $$|g(z)|=\exp(|f(z)|)=\; .\;.\;.$$
  should be
  $$|g(z)|=|\exp(f(z))|= \;.\;.\;.$$

  Also (really minor):$\;$For the inequality
  $$|z| > 1\iff \frac{1}{|z|}\leq 1$$
  the LHS is strict and the RHS is non-strict.$\\[10pt]$

  Finally, your conclusion needs to be fixed:

  Since $f$ is constant, the condition
  $$\Re (f(z))\leq \frac{2}{|z|}$$
  for all $z$ with $|z| > 1$ implies
  $$\Re (f(z))\leq 0$$
  hence $f$ must be a constant with *nonpositive* real part.$\\[10pt]$

Other than that, your argument looks good.

Comment: One other mistake : you forgot that the real part is $\leq 2$ if $|z|>1$, so you need a compactness argument for the other $z$ and thus a possibly different constant.

Comment: @Paul: Other than $f$ being constant, the only other requirement is for the real part of $f$ to be $\le 0$.

Comment: Thanks so much both of you ^.^